# Can anyone explain why there is a 0 in srand(time(0)?

Tags: c++, srand

I have just begun to program with C++ and come across `srand(time(0))`. Can anyone explain why there is a 0 in `srand(time(0))`?

Comment: RTLM: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/ While we're happy to help, this is something you could have trivially looked up yourself.

Comment: How is this either too localized or NARQ?  It's just poor research effort.  Don't vote to close a question just because you don't like it.

Comment: Also, it's a good question.  I expect that this SO question will finish with a clearer, complete answer than on cplusplus.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's the signature of the C `time` function: It requires a pointer to a location to store the time, or null. In this case `0` is the same as a literal null pointer (which means don't store the time in an alternate location).

Answer (score 1):

It seeds the random number generator with the current time value so it gets a new value each time the program is run.

The 0 is equivalent to NULL. The parameter to `time()` takes a pointer to a `time_t` in which the result can also be stored.